# Accessing WPF UI Elements in a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, automation

I have searched around and haven't yet found an answer for my question. In short, I am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483216.aspx) introductory guide to UI automation and am trying to implement a similar design to automate UI testing in my program.

With background out of the way, basically what is happening is no UI element in a Grid I have set up is being set, thus triggering the == null section of the if-else statement. So below is an example of trying to set the Login button, but the same problem exists with other elements like text boxes and other buttons.

```
//Get LogIn Button
AutomationElement aeLogInButton = null;

aeLogInButton = aeP.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "LoginButton"));

//Tell user if LogIn button was received
Console.WriteLine("Before if Statement");
if(aeLogInButton == null)
{
    throw new Exception("No Login Button!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Login Button Found");
}
Console.WriteLine("After if-else");
```

I had to shorten the window name for compliance purposes, but I assure you it is written accurately. In addition, the x:Name of the Login button in the XAML file is "LoginButton" so the NameProperty should be working. I am at a loss for why it is not finding these UI elements. I would appreciate any help or assistance you all could provide.

Comment: Instead of posting broken link to image with code, just post the code as text.

Comment: Are you searching your element inside a data / item template?

Comment: @Athari I have added the code block, sorry about that.

Comment: @Fred No not that I am aware of. It is just a typical XAML file with a grid added for formatting purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the TreeScope.Children to TreeScope.Descendants worked perfectly. Thanks for everyone's help.